# MySQL Insert Query asks for resource

Tags: php, mysql, parameters, insert, resources

I am running the following code on xampp (perfectly installed). I have replaced mysql with mysqli and rearranged the query (connection fisrt, insert into statement later) but all to no avail. Please help.

Error:
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 19

```
<?php


    $hname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "test";

    $connect = mysql_connect($hname, $username, $password, $db);


    if ($connect) {
        echo "Connected to Database <br /> <br />";

        $ins = "INSERT INTO 'test'.'testtable' (name) VALUES ('james')";

        //mysql_select_db ($connect, "users");

        if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'test'.'testtable' (name) VALUES ('james')", "mysql_connect($hname, $username, $password, $db)")) {
            echo "Values Entered Successfully. Your Account was created";
        } else {
            echo "Your Account was not created";

        }

    }   else {
            echo "Failed to Connect :(";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `$db` argument in mysql_connect. Remove that.

Check this link for `mysql_connect` parameters http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Why are you passing `mysql_connect($hname, $username, $password)` with mysql_query. You are already creating a connection before the MySQL query. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by `mysql_connect()` is assumed.

But if you are so particular of passing the connect statement in to query, you should pass as the resource. Currently you are passing as a string. Don't enclose connect statement in quotes.

Also remove the single quotes around the db and table name .

What you need is :

```
if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO test.testtable (name) VALUES ('hunaid')", mysql_connect($hname, $username, $password))) {
    echo "Values Entered Successfully. Your Account was created";
} else {
   echo "Your Account was not created";

}
```

But I think this is enough

```
if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO test.testtable (name) VALUES ('hunaid')")) {
    echo "Values Entered Successfully. Your Account was created";
} else {
   echo "Your Account was not created";
}
```

No need to specify the connect statement since you have already created it at the top.

Also, instead of specifying the db in the query. Add `mysql_select_db` to select the dB before you run query.

So the complete thing will be :

```
$hname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "test";

$connect = mysql_connect($hname, $username, $password);

if ($connect) {

    echo "Connected to Database <br /> <br />";

    mysql_select_db($db);

    $ins = "INSERT INTO testtable (name) VALUES ('james')";

    if (mysql_query($ins)) {
         echo "Values Entered Successfully. Your Account was created";
    } else {
        echo "Your Account was not created";

    }
}   else {
    echo "Failed to Connect :(";
}
```

More over avoid use of mysql* functions.

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [**MySQLi**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 2):

`"mysql_connect($hname, $username, $password, $db)"` should not be in quotes. You want to call the function and pass the result as the argument, not pass a string.

But you really should call it as a separate statement, so you can check for errors:

```
$con = mysql_connect($hname, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect to DB: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db, $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'test'.'testtable' (name) VALUES ('hunaid')", $con);
```

Another problem with your code is that the success of `mysql_query` does not indicate whether any rows were inserted, it just indicates that the query was syntactically valid. You need to call `mysql_affected_rows()` to find out how many rows were inserted.

You really shouldn't use the mysql extensions, they are deprecated. You should use mysqli or PDO. This will allow you to use prepared statements, to avoid SQL injection problems.

Comment: the error vanished but "james" (the value) isn't entered in the database

Comment: You're also giving too many arguments to `mysql_connect()`. There's no `$db` argument, you have to do that separately with `mysql_select_db()`. See my updated answer.

Comment: thank you did it the way you asked me to, got this error: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 20

Comment: You need to read the documentation of mysqli. The arguments are not the same as for the corresponding mysql functions. It's `mysqli_query($con, "INSERT ...");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to connect.

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());


For the MYSQL INSERT try:


mysql_query("INSERT INTO testtable (name) VALUES('hunaid') ") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You also can use to connect your DB this:        mysql_connect($hname, $username, $password) ...   and then mysql_select_db($db) ...